# Set all links on Android app to open in-app like Twitter and not browser

Tags: java, android

I have been searching solution to this I only see solution on how to make individual links open within app.

How can can I set my android studio project (Java) which is is social network app, to open all links in-app like Twitter.

I want it to detect all links and display it without leaving the app and not just individual links

Comment: Have you tried webview?

Comment: I wish to implement it across all activities in app, how to I set that

Comment: pass link to webview activity through intent... that's it